# How does this operation approximately normalize a vector?

Tags: vectors

I am reading through a paper and it is mentioning the normalization (unit length) of vectors. The standard way to normalize $x$ is to compute $x/(x^Tx)^{1/2}$, i.e. divide by its magnitude. However the author works out an approximation for this operation based on a Taylor series, and I can't derive how they get the expressions:

[image]

Can someone help me see how these equations came about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $u$ for the dot product $x^Tx$. The claim is that if $u$ is near $1$, then $1/\sqrt u$ is near $\frac12(3-u)$. This follows from a Taylor expansion of $f(u):=u^{-1/2}$ near $u=1$:

$$u^{-1/2}=:f(u)\approx f(1)+(u-1)f'(1) = 1 + (u-1)(-1/2) = \frac12(3-u)$$

since $f'(u)=(-1/2)u^{-3/2}$.